# Excel spreadsheet is showing all 65536 rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

There's an important spreadsheet that I use in work with around 5000 rows of data, and is updated daily.

Someone has formatted the entire columns to have full borders, thus extending the spreadsheet all the way down to its maximum; 65536 (old Excel).

Now, this has caused the file to get very large and has also meant that whenever I try and use PowerQuery with this worksheet, transformations take ages to complete as PQ is checking all 65536 rows.

Now, I've searched extensively for a solution to this. My attempts:

(1) Use the Inquire add in and select "Clear Excess Formatting". This simply does nothing to my spreadsheet. Although, I have a similar spreadsheet on a different sheet (same workbook), and it clears all of the excess formatting (simply blank rows but with full borders around each cell)  on this sheet, but not my original sheet?

(2) Selected the row where the rows of blank rows begin and press CTRL + Shift + Down to highlight all of the empty rows. Right clicked and deleted these rows. Saved the file. Re-opened, and absolutely nothing has changed.

These are the two methods suggested, but neither of them work for me?

Comment: What I've done in cases like this is select and copy the used cells and then paste into a new spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all might work

Select the row where the rows of blank rows begin and press CTRL + Shift + Down to highlight all of the empty rows.

Home tab > Editing > Clear drop down > clear all

Answer (score 0):

Couple of approaches:

1. Create a new spreadsheet. Copy all the desired portion of the bad spreadsheet over onto the same place in the new spreadsheet. Copy the EXACT name of the bad one from Explorer using Rename and Copy. Without leaving that Rename effort, actually Rename it by adding a 1 to the end, before its ".XLS" of course. Paste the name somewhere easy to copy it from again. Save the new spreadsheet (as a `.XLS` file!) using the Copied name. Close it. Re-open it. See how that all works. Loads of things can happen here, but hopefully the "someone" did not do other unfortunate things as well.

Naturally, if there are complications like macros and such, bring them into the new spreadsheet. Named Ranges and Conditional Formatting should come with the cells they affect or are used in or affect. Any of such that do not, are things that are not actually in use so probably don't matter, although it's possible Named Ranges might be used by VBA but not the sheets. If life is complicated like that, or similarly, try the other approach first.

The point is that this will work for most spreadsheets and only nasty beasts (like ones that started out a bit complex 20 years ago and have had many motherless sons do things the way "someone" did this...) will be a problem. And honestly, lots of those will BENEFIT from this kind of thing... net of the suffering that might occur.

2. Insert a new page/sheet, and do nothing to it. Just... nothing. Don't format anything, don't do anything to it. Copy ANY single cell. Go to the bad spreadsheet and find the "right edge":  the first column after which there should be nothing at all, especially no formatting. Highlight it all from there down to the bottom and to the very right edge of the sheet. Paste that bare cell over it all. Find the "bottom edge" below which nothing should exist and do the same. Save and close the file. Open it back up and see if things have improved. Very good chance not as Excel did not ever, I believe, sense the used area of a .XLS file and remove areas the current session thinks in use, but that are not really so, during a save. That's expected, so cool. Find the right edge again and highlight again. Delete all those columns. Find the bottom edge again and do the same thing to delete all the rows underneath the really used area. Save and close again. Re-open. Should be good. (Oh, after dong the pasting, above, delete the inserted sheet you got the cell from.)

Actually, don't open a new spreads

Seems simple, but it could backfire a little:  You might have 143 sheets, some Hidden and well-hidden at that. I bet the "someone" did not have the "stick-to-itiveness" to do it to many of them, but... maybe he really hated you all and did. But do it for each page necessary and you should be golden.

For either, and for almost any other salvage of the situation, the age of the file will be critical. The older it is, the more likely it is there is a ton of garbage, and even more garbage that is gone, but left some pieces behind. If it ever had links or pics, there's a ton of ways those things lead to corruption. The good side is that those things ought not to ever be activated in any way so if they end up not locatable by Excel, well, it isn't ever going to look for them again either. But... life is complex and complicated. Definitely have a backup or three before doing anything.

There's another angle as well, an odd one, and maybe not one you need worry about. I've worked in places where I was not permitted to improve the files. Even for my own work. I'm sure there were good reasons... sure there were... but I never let that hold me back. I'd create things for myself that I left not working. Named Ranges for example, all started with my first name, that I then quick-built inserted pages that did the work for me faster and more accurately. Deleted said pages after doing the work and putting it in place where it was expected. But not the Named Ranges. I'm no VBA guru, but can do a basic bit of work. I would put tricky pieces of macros into Named Ranges (that obviously did nothing), then rewrite the macros in a couple minutes, copying the tricky bits from the Named Range "Refers to" boxes. Do my work, delete macros, all done. I've never noticed myself to be unique amongst humanity, so you may aggravate some folks by this kind of thing not moving forward with the nice new file in approach 1. But... they were breaking the rules so... but you might want to ask around for that kind of thing before fixing the file. Mmm... or not ask around, if you think there's nothing like that and don't want to put the idea into peoples' heads. There are plenty of "someones" out there and not all are... um, perfect at it like I was... so...